# Spy++-like tool for OpenGL render trees

Tags: opengl, syntax, spy++

is anybody here aware of a Spy++-like tool which lets me visualize the object tree of graphical elements in an OpenGL scene? If possible (Spy++ lets you do this), it would be great if the tool didn't require support being built into the application.

I'm not too familiar with OpenGL yet, but maybe what I'm after is a view on the tree structure of the render tree in an OpenGL scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the geometry hits OpenGL it's just a big pile of triangles.  Any sort of scenegraph is (mostly) lost.  You might have some luck looking at the glPush/PopMatrix() sequences from a [GLIntercept](http://glintercept.nutty.org/) dump, but that's assuming the app doesn't maintain transform state itself.

Answer (score 1):

[gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/) from Graphic Remedy is the best OpenGL debugging tool, it'll let you view the geometry in various stages of rendering as well as a host of other things.  What it won't do is let you view application-specific structures like (as genpfault said) scene-graphs, rendering trees, and spatial partitioning.

Many times however, you can extrapolate the information from the OpenGL calls.

Oh, and if you have an nVidia card don't forget about NVPerfKit, which lets you have some real-time control over scenes.